# Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)$ is continuous …

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)$ is continuous. If $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)f'(x)\le 0$ for all $x>0$, prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\ge0$.

Comment: so... what is your attempt?

Comment: Maybe $2f(x)f'(x)\leq 0$ would put you on the right track faster?

Comment: @julien twice as fast, in fact.

Comment: @IgorRivin Approximately. I wonder what would be the effect of removing the unnecessary "$f'(x)$ is continuous" assumption, though.

Comment: @julien Might be another factor of 2, since this probably just confuses the OP.

Comment: I am a little confused myself on how to do this correctly (I have not had real analysis), so I deleted my (bad) answer. Can I just use $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(x)$ for small $x$ to get an easy contradiction when assuming f(x) is positive or negative somehow?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Let $g(x) = (f(x))^2$. We know that $g(0) = 0$. What can you say about $g'(x)$?