# Prove that if $f(x)f'(x) \le 0 \space\space\space\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$, then $f = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I found a problem in my old real analysis textbook, and tried my hand at it, but am having a little trouble finishing:

> Prove that if $f(x)f'(x) \le 0 \space\space\space\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$, then $f = 0$

First consider $x<0$. We must either have:

$f(x) \le 0$ and $f'(x) \ge 0 \space\space\space$ or $\space\space\space f(x) \ge 0$ and $f'(x) \le 0$

These cases have an obvious symmetry, so we choose one without any loss in generality.

To see that $\operatorname{sgn}(f)$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(f')$ are constant for $x<0$, let's assume $f(x) \le 0$ with $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x \le x_1 < 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for $x_1 < x < 0$. Clearly, this implies $f(x_1) = 0$.

By mean value theorem $\exists c \in (x_1, x)$ s.t.
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)}{x - x_1} > 0$$

So that, namely, $f(c)f'(c) > 0$, which contradicts our assumption.

Thus, we can say $f(x) \le 0$ and $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x< 0$.

If $f(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$, $\exists c \in (0, x)$ such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)}{x} < 0$$

so that $f(c)f'(c) > 0$

Similarly, we can find that that if $f(x) > 0$ for $x>0$, then $\exists c$ such that $f(c)f'(c) > 0$

So the only option is that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \ge 0$

I am thinking from here, I can assume that $f(x) < 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x< 0$ and find a contradiction, but I am not certain how to do it. I believe if such a contradiction exists, it will come from showing that $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$, which may amount to showing the left-handed limit does not approach $0$, but I also have no real reason to think that is the case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't $$f(x) = \cases{x^2 & if $x<0$\\0 & if $x\geq 0$}$$fulfill the criteria in the problem?

Comment: For $x > 0$ it is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/607098/42969. For $x < 0$ the conclusion is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR: I see, perhaps I misread the problem statement! That would certainly explain the difficulty I was facing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To prove $f(x) = 0$ for $x\geq 0$, note that
$$
f(x)f'(x) = \frac12\left[f(x)f(x)\right]'
$$
so we are told that

- $(f(x))^2$ is a decreasing function
- $(f(0))^2 = 0$

so we must have $(f(x))^2 = 0$ for any $x\geq 0$, because it can never be negative.

Finally, we can't say much about what happens for $x\leq 0$, since any differentiable, monotonous function $f$ with $f(x) = 0$ for $x\geq 0$ fulfills the criteria set in the problem. For a concrete example:
$$
f(x) = \cases{x^2 & if $x<0$\\0 & if $x\geq 0$}
$$

Comment: Wow! Looks as though my problem statement doesn't even hold for $x<0$, so I can actually use mean value theorem as I did (with maybe an extra couple lines) to prove it. However, this is proof is absolutely beautiful and far simpler!

Comment: @infinitylord Whenever you have a derivative multiplied by something non-constant, it's a good idea to check for product rule (or quotient rule), to see if it simplifies matters. Even if you have to manipulate the expression to make it on the product rule form. The standard method for solving first order linear differential equations (with non-constant coefficients) is based on this idea, for instance, with the keyword being integrating factor.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f(x)\leq 0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\geq 0$. What does this mean geometrically? $f(x)$ starts at $0$ it can only stay below the upper half plane, additionally $f'(x)\geq 0$ implies that $f(x)$ does not change or increases. If we start at $0$ and the value does not change then we have $f(x)\equiv 0$. If we start at $0$ and the value increases, then we violate $f(x)\leq 0$, Hence $f(x)\equiv 0$. You can procede the same way for the other set of inequalities.